# systemd timer for a process that runs every 5 minutes, but may run longer than 5 minutes

Tags: systemd

I did a little searching and didn't see any similar questions.

I have a job that should run once every five minutes.

There should only be one job running at a time.

If the program takes more than 5 minutes to run, it should start again immediately, not wait.

Most of the time, the job will complete in under a minute, occasionally it must do things that might take as long as 20 minutes.

I currently run this job as a systemd service, and the job is a shell script that calls the actual program in a loop, and sleeps between iterations (5 minutes - last run time).  It works great.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Sample executable repeat-loop
#
# Run my job in a loop.  If it takes less than max_delay seconds
# to run, sleep until it's time to repeat.  If, for some reason, it took longer, just start
# over again immediately.

max_delay=300                       # maximum delay between runs

# Don't allow multiple copies of this script to run
[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@"

restart=0
now=0

while true ; do
    now=`date -u '+%s'`
    if [ $restart -gt $now ] ; then
        sleep `expr $restart - $now`
    fi
    restart=`expr $now + ${max_delay}`

    echo "my job runs here and may take between 30 seconds and 20 minutes to execute"
done
```

Since I am a bloody idiot, I was thinking it would be great to change this to a oneshot service, and have systemd timers fire off.

I haven't been able to figure out how to emulate this behavior using `OnUnitActiveSec` or `OnUnitInactiveSec`...

`OnUnitActiveSec` is going to fire up my oneshot service every x seconds.
`OnUnitInactiveSec` is going to fire up my oneshot x seconds after the last time the oneshot terminated.

Any thoughts besides "Hey, your shell script works great, why beat yourself with a dead horse?"

Comment: Huh? Did systemd really attempt to start your service when it was already running?

Comment: The flock is my paranoia.

Comment: Or do you mean that you believe that OnUnitActive should be sufficient?

Comment: Wait, so you didn't actually try anything yet?

Comment: No, from my reading of the docs, I didn't think it would work the way I needed, but now you have me second guessing myself. If the service type is simple or oneshot and it's not an @ service, maybe OnUnitActiveSec is exactly what I want?

Answer (score 5):

I should have tested better, rather than relying on my (incorrect) interpretation of the docs.

Creating a timer file and using `OnUnitActiveSec` pointing to a service file that is `Type=simple` does exactly what I want.  The timer will be invoked every 5 minutes, if the process runs longer than 5 minutes, it will be invoked (almost) immediately.  It will not be double-invoked.

It's important to use `simple` instead of `oneshot` (per the docs).

Comment: I didn't see any reference to `simple` in the docs - do you have a reference please?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html